# What is "return (var > -1)" in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have seen a piece of code in the web.

```
function isMobile() {
var index = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile");
return (index > -1);
}
```

Why can't we just check if index is > or < 0? Please explain returning index > -1.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the result of [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is `-1`, the string was not found. `0` would indicate that is is in the string, and that it is, in fact, at the start of the string.

Therefore, if you tested for `> 0`, then you'd be checking if it existed somewhere not at the start of the string. `!(index < 0)` and `index >= 0` would both work, too, but the former is a little more complex than it needs to be.

If you were confused about the syntax, returning the result of a comparison is the same as returning `true` if the comparison results in `true` and returning `false` when the comparison results in `false`.

Comment: Yeah, the check should probably be "index != -1".

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns -1 when "Mobile" isn't in `navigator.appVersion`. Returning `(index > -1)` is equivalent to returning `true` if "Mobile" is in `navigator.appVersion`, and `false` if it isn't.